# Eclipse won't read images from drawable

Tags: android

I was working on some project and everything was fine, but yesterday i replaced some images in drawable folder and the old pictures are still there and won't replace and i get and error "Image cannot be resolved or is not a field"  (i was doing that before and everything worked fine). I reinstalled android development kit and downloaded everything again and nothing.

Please help, thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/laedA.png

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information here. What have you tried? What does your project layout look like? Do you get any errors when you try to run the project? Have you checked the console output?

Comment: I have errors "Image cannot be resolved or is not a filled"

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of eclipse with your drawable folders expanded and with the console open please?

Comment: @user3901899 .... Check my answer .... Try possible debugging strategies !

Comment: I've uploaded the image (http://i.stack.imgur.com/laedA.png)

Comment: Thanks. Can you post your styles.XML file please?

Comment: @IanNewson .... Op has named the images using integers for file names causing R.java not to generate ....which is causing the error ....Looks to me my solution fits well !

Comment: @Devrath sorry, you're incorrect. Integers are valid in resource names, as long as they're not the first character. I've verified this myself in my own project. If integers were not allowed in resource names then surely `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` would mean Android would not build at all. I don't know what the posters problem was, but it's not integers in resource names. I'm tempted to downvote your answer because of this but it's only fair to give the opportunity to correct it first.

Comment: @ Ian Newson .... So unless the integers are added at first in resource name .... it wont give error ! ... Thanks for correcting me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Scenario 1:**: You have deleted images in `drawable`-folder but same named images are present in `drawable-hdpi,ldpi,mdpi` folders
- **Scenario 2**:: Delete the old images and then add the new ones
- **Scenario 3**:: Check the naming conventions for the images, make sure all are lower case and you don't use integers
- **Scenario 4**:: Use a different image with different name and reference

---

### {EDIT-1}:: On Quote:: `I have errors "Image cannot be resolved or is not a filled"`

***This is caused because you have deleted the image and there is no image and still you are referencing it in your project***

---

### {EDIT-2}::

instead of
`import android.R`

Changing it to following for ex:: 
`import com.example.app.R`

- Try deleting the `R.Java` and clean the eclipse and then again run the
  project

---

### {EDIT-3}

`Scenario 3` ..... I explained clearly you cannot use integers for `imagename`..... instead of for example `c3pipe13` name it as `c_three_pipe_thirteen` ......... do the same for all the images ...... that is what causing the error

***Hope this helps, let me know if you need any information***

Comment: i checked everything and still nothing, same error.

Comment: It's the name of the image, but yesterday everything was working fine

Comment: @user3901899 ...Check my `edit3` in my answer ....... i think with that you can resolve your error

Comment: For some reason i don't have R.java

Comment: @user3901899 ......... `R.java` wont be generated until you have those errors ............. do as i suggested in `edit-3` ...let me know you if you have any problems !

Comment: I don't think that name is the problem because yesterday was working well without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your project or rename the new file and set it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't old images in other drawable folders (hdpi, mdpi etc). If you have delete it, clean and build project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe drag the pictures onto the drawable-folder in your eclipse-projecttree. Then select copy files.